# How to show all files modified in a specific period?

Tags: date, powershell, where-clause, get-childitem

I have to `dir` every file that got modified in a specific time period with PowerShell.

I found [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/17/powertip-find-files-modified-during-a-date-range-by-using-powershell/). Right now I've got the following statement, but I get an error message.

```
dir C:\Test\ | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt '01/01/2016' -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt '14/02/2016'
}
```

[image: Error Message]

Do I have to convert the date or something?

Comment: thx for the help! ParseExact was the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
$von = Read-Host "pls start date of period (dd.mm.yyyy) : "
$bis = Read-Host "pls end date of period(dd.mm.yyyy): "
$vondate = [datetime]::ParseExact($von,'dd.MM.yyyy',$null)
$bisdate = [datetime]::ParseExact($bis,'dd.MM.yyyy',$null)

dir C:\Test\ | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt $vondate -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $bisdate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error, because your reference dates use a format `dd/MM/yyyy`, which PowerShell can't automatically cast to a `DateTime` value. Either use the US date format (`MM/dd/yyyy`):

```
dir C:\Test\ | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt '01/01/2016' -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt '02/14/2016'
}
```

or use [`Get-Date`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) to create reference dates from strings formatted in your system's locale (most likely `dd.MM.yyyy` since your error message is in German):

```
$maxAge = Get-Date '01.01.2016'
$minAge = Get-Date '14.02.2016'

dir C:\Test\ | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt $maxAge -and
  $_.LastWriteTime -lt $minAge
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I didnt even bother checking the second date.